# Validating IPv4 string in Java

Tags: java, string, validation, ip

Bellow method is validating if string is correct IPv4 address it returns true if it is valid. Any improvements in regex and elegance would be very appreciated:

```
public static boolean validIP(String ip) {
    if (ip == null || ip.isEmpty()) return false;
    ip = ip.trim();
    if ((ip.length() < 6) & (ip.length() > 15)) return false;

    try {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(ip);
        return matcher.matches();
    } catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: There are different representations possible. You are looking for dot-decimal notation: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Address_representations

Comment: an ip.length() of 7 is valid, for example 0.0.0.0 is 7 characters, your method will return false.

Comment: I am wondering why this is still no part of some third party library. I mean avoiding third party libraries is good but figuring the regex for that is highly error-prone which is in my opinion worse than using a third party API.

Comment: The regex is fine, you just have to replace `[0-9]` for `\d`and take the Pattern compilation outside the method so you don't have to compile it everytime.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Here is an easier-to-read, slightly less efficient, way you could go about it.

```
public static boolean validIP (String ip) {
    try {
        if ( ip == null || ip.isEmpty() ) {
            return false;
        }

        String[] parts = ip.split( "\\." );
        if ( parts.length != 4 ) {
            return false;
        }

        for ( String s : parts ) {
            int i = Integer.parseInt( s );
            if ( (i < 0) || (i > 255) ) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        if ( ip.endsWith(".") ) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I prefer this approach more.

Comment: If you do `ip.split("\\.", -1)` you can delete the `if (ip.endsWith(".")) ...` bit

Comment: You might want to check for leading zeroes in each part, see http://superuser.com/questions/857603/are-ip-addresses-with-and-without-leading-zeroes-the-same

Comment: "192.168.1" is a valid IP address. I think your method has a flaw.

Comment: @PEdroArthur Four dotted numbers is a pretty standard representation of an IPV4 address. The dotted octet format was never really specified in an RFC. The first mention is in the MTP RFC (circa 1981) says, "four small decimal integers separated by dots and enclosed by brackets, e.g., "[123.255.37.321]", which indicates a 32 bit ARPA Internet Address in four eight bit fields." Do you have any source that indicates that "192.168.1" is valid?

Comment: @rouble I don't know. However, all network stacks that I use do accept address like 192.168.1 (192.168.0.1) and 10.1 (10.0.0.1).

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/486788/why-does-pinging-192-168-072-only-2-dots-return-a-response-from-192-168-0-58

Comment: Will the above solution work for IPv4Address and IPv6Address as well ,Can you add testing use cases if possible?

Comment: check this "01.233.161.131"

Comment: @rouble,Will the above solution work for IPv4Address and IPv6Address as well ,Can you modify the code for IPV4ADDRESS and IPV6ADDRESS ?

Answer (score 55):

**UPDATE:** Commons-HttpClient and its successor HttpComponents-HttpClient have adopted this functionality. You can utilize this version of it like so: `InetAddressUtils.isIPv4Address(Str)`.

---

The development version of [Apache Commons Validator](http://commons.apache.org/validator/) has a [`InetAddressValidator`](http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/InetAddressValidator.html) class which has a [`isValidInet4Address(String)`](http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/InetAddressValidator.html#isValidInet4Address(java.lang.String)) method to perform a check to see that an given `String` is a valid IPv4 address.

The [source code](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/validator/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/InetAddressValidator.java?view=markup) can be viewed from the repository, so that might provide some ideas for improvements, if you feel there are any.

A quick glance at the provided code shows that your method is compiling a `Pattern` on each invocation of the method. I would move that `Pattern` class out to a `static` field to avoid the costly pattern compilation process on each call.

Comment: InetAddressUtils.isIPv4Address(Str) is java inner API. You should not use it.

Comment: @user918888 it's what? all it does is matches it against regex and returns the result.

Comment: It's part of the apache commons library, its fine. Maybe he thought it was some "com.sun" type internal thing?

Answer (score 22):

If you want to use a library with a released version suppporting both IPv4 and IPv6 support, you can use [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/net/InetAddresses.html)

```
boolean isValid = InetAddresses.isInetAddress("1.2.3.4");
```

Answer (score 17):

If you don't mind using dns resolution on invalid ip-addresses like `www.example.com`, you can use the [InetAddress](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName%28java.lang.String%29) methods to check:

```
public static final boolean checkIPv4(final String ip) {
    boolean isIPv4;
    try {
    final InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
    isIPv4 = inet.getHostAddress().equals(ip)
            && inet instanceof Inet4Address;
    } catch (final UnknownHostException e) {
    isIPv4 = false;
    }
    return isIPv4;
}
```

The method checks if it is an instance of Inet4Address and if the parameter was the ip-address and not the hostname. 
If you expect a lot of hostnames as parameters, beware that this implementation uses DNS to try to resolve it. This might be a performance concern.

Otherwise you can have a peak into 
`boolean sun.net.util.IPAddressUtil.isIPv4LiteralAddress(String src)` how the String is parsed there for IPv4-check.

Comment: FWIW, here's what i usually do: first use a simple regexp to check that the parameter consists of 4 dot-separated numbers (i don't try to check if the numbers are within range, etc, just the general format). If this first check passes, then i use InetAddress as in this answer to finish the validation.

Answer (score 17):

Here's a solution that uses Java 8 streams to check that the address consists of exactly 4 numbers between 0 and 255 inclusive, separated by dots:

```
public class IpValidation {

    /**
     * Check that a string represents a decimal number
     * @param string The string to check
     * @return true if string consists of only numbers without leading zeroes, false otherwise
     */
    public static boolean isDecimal(String string) {
        // Check whether string has a leading zero but is not "0"
        if (string.startsWith("0")) {
            return string.length() == 1;
        }
        for(char c : string.toCharArray()) {
            if(c < '0' || c > '9') {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean isIp(String string) {
        String[] parts = string.split("\\.", -1);
        return parts.length == 4 // 4 parts
                && Arrays.stream(parts)
                .filter(IpValidation::isDecimal) // Only decimal numbers
                .map(Integer::parseInt)
                .filter(i -> i <= 255 && i >= 0) // Must be inside [0, 255]
                .count() == 4; // 4 numerical parts inside [0, 255]
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct in all scenarios. 
This method returns true for 172.013.1.2 which is an invalid IP address string. It should be 172.13.1.2 instead. The 'isNumeric' method can be modified to correct this.

Comment: 172.013.1.2 *is* a valid IP address. As is 172.013.001.002. Leading zeroes are usually avoided though because they may imply that the number is in octal instead of decimal.

Comment: http://www.ipaddressguide.com/ip and http://sqa.fyicenter.com/Online_Test_Tools/IP_Address_Format_Validator.php and https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/InetAddressValidator.html#line.86 Say it is invalid

http://formvalidation.io/validators/ip/ and http://www.csgnetwork.com/directipverify.html?IPvalue=172.013.001.002 say it is valid

Comment: `ping 192.168.001.001` works from terminal in Linux, that's good enough for me :)

Comment: `ping 192.168.1.09`
ping: cannot resolve 192.168.1.09: Unknown host

Summary: IP segment starting with 0 indicates that the segment is in octal, so we also need to validate that the remaining digits do not contain 7,8 (I admit i didn't know this before: thats y i gave the examples as 172.013.1.2 The correct test case to test is 172.13.1.008 - which fails)

Long story short: The above validation is not correct and can lead to false positives

Comment: "works in one case, that's good enough for me." That's plenty of reason for a downvote. Sad that this answer received a bounty. The reason that one case worked is that the numbers starting with `0` (`001` in this case) mean the same in octal as in decimal. That's only true if there is only one  non-zero digit, with no zeroes after it, and that digit isn't 8 or 9.  Yikes.

Comment: Leading zeroes _are_ allowed in IP addresses though, but since the interpretation of them is a bit ambiguous I'll change the answer to not allow leading zeroes.

Comment: Will the above solution work for IPv4Address and IPv6Address as well ,Can you add testing use cases if possible?

Comment: It will definitely _not_ work for IPv6 addresses since they use a completely different format

Comment: @Raniz ,Can you please add the java code for IPv6 addresses .Can you please add the java main method to check for IPv4Address and  IPv6Address testing scenarios?

Comment: I suggest you search SO for a similar question or ask one yourself if you can't find one since that is different problem

Answer (score 7):

Find regex example from [this](http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-ip-address-with-regular-expression/)

```
package com.mkyong.regex;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class IPAddressValidator{

    private Pattern pattern;
    private Matcher matcher;

    private static final String IPADDRESS_PATTERN = 
        "^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
        "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
        "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
        "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$";

    public IPAddressValidator(){
      pattern = Pattern.compile(IPADDRESS_PATTERN);
    }

   /**
    * Validate ip address with regular expression
    * @param ip ip address for validation
    * @return true valid ip address, false invalid ip address
    */
    public boolean validate(final String ip){         
      matcher = pattern.matcher(ip);
      return matcher.matches();             
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct in all scenarios. This method returns true for 172.013.1.2 which is an invalid IP address string. It should be 172.13.1.2 instead.

Comment: @radiantRazor  172.013.1.2 is a valid address, albeit probably misleading, since 013 is often interpreted a octal, i.e. 11. See [Dot-decimal notation] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot-decimal_notation).

Answer (score 5):

In think this solution is quite elegant, although it takes a minute to understand it.

The basic idea is to take a sub-string and than validate it.
 Please note that I switch x and y, since the start of a sub-string will always be the end of the last one plus 1.

This solution is about 20x faster than a regex variant and 2x faster than splitting.

```
public static boolean validIP(String ip) {
    if(ip == null || ip.length() < 7 || ip.length() > 15) return false;

    try {
        int x = 0;
        int y = ip.indexOf('.');

        if (y == -1 || ip.charAt(x) == '-' || Integer.parseInt(ip.substring(x, y)) > 255) return false;

        x = ip.indexOf('.', ++y);
        if (x == -1 || ip.charAt(y) == '-' || Integer.parseInt(ip.substring(y, x)) > 255) return false;

        y = ip.indexOf('.', ++x);
        return  !(y == -1 ||
                ip.charAt(x) == '-' ||
                Integer.parseInt(ip.substring(x, y)) > 255 ||
                ip.charAt(++y) == '-' ||
                Integer.parseInt(ip.substring(y, ip.length())) > 255 ||
                ip.charAt(ip.length()-1) == '.');

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you know that you'll have a lot wrong IPs consider adding the following code below the first if. This will make the code 1.5x slower but in case of an error improve it by 700x

```
    for (int i = 0; i < ip.length(); i++) {
        if (!Character.isDigit(ip.charAt(i)) && ip.charAt(i) != '.') return false;
    }
```

Comment: Will the above solution work for IPv4Address and IPv6Address as well ,Can you add testing use cases if possible using main() method

Comment: It is the fastest function that I have tested for IPv4 but can we extend it for IPv6 also?

Answer (score 5):

Try using the following regrex for IPv4

```
String ip4Regex="^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[0-9]{1,2})(\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[0-9]{1,2})){3}$";
```

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 4):

If you use the code in the question, you'll want to change the line:

```
if ((ip.length() < 6) & (ip.length() > 15)) return false;
```

to

```
if ((ip.length() <= 6) || (ip.length() > 15)) return false;
```

Answer (score 4):

Most of the answers (except that of Michael Konietzka) are wrong: 10.8, for instance, is a valid IP4 address (a shorthand for 10.0.0.8).

See[Textual representation of IP addresses](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Inet4Address.html#format) in the Java specifications.

As may be seen in the reference, to check a numeric representation, there may be 1 to 4 parts, and in each case different limitations on the parts apply.

Answer (score 3):

I think the proper way is to build an `IPAddress` class and instanciate it by giving it a string representation of the the ip address.

This way you can split out the different validation steps into instance methods and get some [separation of concern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) going.

For instance, this here is typically it's own method, call this simply `isEmpty`:

```
return (ip == null || ip.isEmpty());
```

Also this should be a separate method, you could call this one `hasProbableLength`.

```
ip = ip.trim();
return ((ip.length() < 6) & (ip.length() > 15));
```

Here there are lots of things going on. I would try to break this up and perhaps try to skip the regex completely.

```
try {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(ip);
    return matcher.matches();
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    return false;
}
```

I would first split the string on dots and see that I get exactly four groups. Call this method `divideIntoGroups`

I would then validate each of the groups for being a value between 0 and 255. Call this method `validateGroups`

Now that you have this, if you ever want to extend this class to also look for if the IP is localhost or if it is a broadcast address, it is pretty easy to do this. This is what [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) gives you.

You can also tell exactly which one of your validation rules was broken in the validation of the IP address string. Something that regex will not.

Comment: Can you add the java code and testing use cases if possible using main() method ?

Answer (score 3):

[The IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) will do it.  The javadoc is available at the link.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager.

This library supports IPv4 and IPv6 transparently, so validating either works the same below, and it also supports CIDR prefix-length IPC4 addresses as well.  It supports the more unusual formats like inet_aton (for example 10.8 was mentioned in another answer here)

Verify if an address is valid:

```
    String str = "1.2.3.4";
    IPAddressString addrString = new IPAddressString(str);
    try {
         IPAddress addr = addrString.toAddress();
         ...
    } catch(AddressStringException e) {
        //e.getMessage provides validation issue
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Most simple way I found to check given ip is correctly in ipv4 is to use commons-validator-1.4.0.jar has class:--

```
org.apache.commons.validator.routines.InetAddressValidator
```

[InetAddressValidator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/InetAddressValidator.html)

E.g.

```
InetAddressValidator inetValidator = InetAddressValidator.getInstance();
inetValidator.isValidInet4Address(yourIPAddress);
```

which uses this simple regex :--

```
  "^(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})$";
```

Comment: That regex accepts 999.999.999.999 though so is pretty useless

Answer (score 2):

It will be useful for you,

```
boolean isIPv4Address(String inputString) {
    String[] splitString = inputString.split("[.]");
    if (splitString.length > 4) {
        return false;
    }
    for (String string : splitString) {
        if (string.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!string.matches("[0-9]{1,3}")) {
            return false;
        }
        int number = Integer.parseInt(string);
        if (!(number >= 0 && number <= 255)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Will the above solution work for IPv4Address and IPv6Address as well ,Can you add testing use cases if possible?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using what's available on the platform/framework you are developing.

If there's nothing you consider good enough, then you might just want to add a compiled regex to a helper class. For instance, [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/util/Patterns.java#120)'s how the Android framework does it:

```
public static final Pattern IP_ADDRESS
    = Pattern.compile(
        "((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9])\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4]"
        + "[0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9]|0)\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]"
        + "[0-9]{2}|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9]|0)\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}"
        + "|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9]))");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean isValid = inetAddressValidator.isValid(hostName) || hostName.equalsIgnoreCase("localhost");
```

same answer as coobird. Just add localhost to the statement. Most of the environments takes 'localhost' as a valid host name. It is not a ipv4 format but it should be included to consider validity.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean ipv4Check(String ipAddress){

    try{
        if(ipAddress!=null && !ipAddress.isEmpty()){
            String [] ip = ipAddress.split("\\.");
            if(ip.length!=4)
                return false;

            for(int i=0;i<=ip.length-1;i++){
                int j=Integer.parseInt(ip[i]);
                if(j<0 || j>255){
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if ( ipAddress.endsWith(".") ) {
                return false;
            }
            if ( ipAddress.startsWith(".") ) {
                return false;
            }

        }
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        return false;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Will the above solution work for IPv4Address and IPv6Address as well ,Can you add testing use cases if possible?

Comment: This is to check ipv4 not ipv6 as both have different structure

Comment: Can you add the java solution for IPv6Address as well Can you add testing use cases for IPv4Address and IPv6Address from public static void main method in java @Amit Kumar