# How do I check if a text contains an IP address?

Tags: java, ip

I've searched around but have not found anything that works. How do I check if a text contains an IP address? I have tried this but it does not work:

```
    public boolean ip(String a_text) {
    String ip_filter = "\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}";
    if (a_text.toLowerCase().contains(ip_filter.toLowerCase())){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You should use `matches()`, not `contains()`.

Comment: possibly duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581877/validating-ipv4-string-in-java

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov, it's important to say that if OP uses `matches` than the regex needs to match with the whole String. Just as if it had begin/and anchors on the pattern.

Comment: @RodrigoSasaki Yes, you're right. I didn't notice this. `Pattern` and `Matcher` seem more appropriate for this task, I think.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're trying to use a [Regular Expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) with the `contains` method. And that method does not receive a regex as argument. It receives a plain String. You should try using [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).

Here's an example:

```
public static boolean ip(String text) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
    return m.find();
}
```

**EDIT**: I updated the pattern to a more suitable one, found [here](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/318-how-to-match-ipv4-addresses-with-regular-expressions/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use match, and a better regular expression that I have used in the past is:

```
((0|1[0-9]{0,2}|2[0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|[3-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(0|1[0-9]{0,2}|2[0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|[3-9][0-9]?)
```

From [RegExLib](http://regexlib.com/?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a lot of things with Regex. But Why should you!? You already have good and tested libraries, like [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/net/InetAddresses.html)

```
boolean isValid = InetAddresses.isInetAddress("1.2.3.4");
```

[Appache Validator](http://commons.apache.org/validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/InetAddressValidator.html)

```
 isValidInet4Address(String)
```

And so on (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581877/validating-ipv4-string-in-java) post)