# checking String for symbols

Tags: java, error-handling, character

I have a string input by the user that should represent an IP address like: 123.234.12.8
but being a silly person as they can be sometimes what if they enter: 12#.234.1@.8

I've figured out how check for characters and symbols by looping through the string and making temporary chars/ints using:

```
tempChar = ipString.charAt(i);
tempInt = Character.getNumericValue(tempChar);
```

I can flag a 'a' or a 'q' but I can't differentiate between the '.' symbol and others such as '#' or '&' because they're all given the int value -1.

Is there an existing method for preventing users entering any symbol except a '.' or can someone point me in the right direction if I'm going about this wrong?

EDIT: This is in Java.

Comment: Can you just use a regular expression for this?

Comment: Are you just trying to validate this data, or remove the bad characters too? Either way, as @MadProgrammer said, regular expressions are great option here. Please clarify your question to get a better answer.

Comment: For [example](http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-ip-address-with-regular-expression/) or [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667371/validate-ipv4-address-in-java)

Comment: This might be useful [Remove Special Characters in the String in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21074485/remove-special-characters-in-the-string-in-java)

Comment: I'm trying to validate it, if the IP has invalid characters in it I want to ask the user to input a new one.

I'm not familiar with regular expressions, on oracle tutorials right now reading through it.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Perfect, I don't quite understand what's happening so I'll have to read up on regular expressions but it looks like that's what I need to learn :)

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Just test the actual characters instead of the value you get from `Character.getNumericValue` and don't call things tempThis and tempThat -- that's a terrible naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression. In this case, you'll want (roughly):

```
Pattern pattern = new Pattern.compile("(\\d{1,3}\\.){4}");
```

which you can then use as follows:

```
boolean isMatch = pattern.matcher(ipString).matches;
```

This isn't extremely precise in terms of validating an IP address -- better answers are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667371/validate-ipv4-address-in-java). But it does answer your question as written: it excludes symbols except for a "." separating digits.

Answer (score 0):

You should use regex.

```
    String ipString = "123.234.12@8";
    System.out.println(ipString.matches("^\\d+(\\.\\d+){3}$"));
```

[**matches**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) will return true only if user inputs a sequence of digits and dots.

> *public boolean matches(String regex)* : 
>   Tells whether or not this string matches the given regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

- [using the JDK pattern matching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15690025/2446396)
- [using the JDK InetAddress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4583301/2446396)
- [using Apache Commons Validator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4581925/2446396)