# How to identify patterns of repeated characters within string?

Tags: java, regex, string

Lets say you have a string like this:

```
198<string>12<string>88<string>201
```

Yes that looks like an IPv4 address, because it is one.

How do i check to see if there are repeated patterns in a string?
I've no idea where to start, and im not sure that regex would help since i dont really know what string to look for, just that it will be repeated.

The goal here is to strip `<string>` from the main string.

Okay lets say the string is:

```
String test = "112(dot)115(dot)48(dot)582";
if(isIP(test){
   System.out.println("Yep, it's an ip");
}
```

The output should be:

```
Yep, it's an ip
```

The seperator (dot) will always be different.

Comment: Could you give some example?

Comment: Provide some valid input and expected output?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validating IPv4 string in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581877/validating-ipv4-string-in-java)

Comment: @ThatGuy343 Is "112(color)115(color)48(colour)582"; valid?

Comment: no, the separators being the same is fine, atleast for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: https://regex101.com/r/oR1gS8/4

```
/^((?:\d{1,3}[^0-9]+){3}\d{1,3})$/
```

Matches `198<string>12<string>88<string>201`, `112(dot)115(dot)48(dot)582`, and `112<test>115<test>48<test>582`, among others...

Comment: it will check correct ip in this example 11223472938(dot)115(dot)48(dot)582  but this isn't valid.

Comment: 192.1.1 is Invalid IP4 but your regex returns true for it

Comment: Fixed... Take a look at the original post.

Comment: It will say `12x23.34-45` as valid.

Comment: Is it not? @ThatGuy343 implied the delimiter could be any string. The one weakness this regex has is that it'll allow groups with values above 255, which can be fixed if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
/((((\d{1,3})\D{1,5}){3})(\d{1,3}))$/
```

> 112(dot)115(dot)48(dot)582

Matches

```
1.  [0-26]  `112(dot)115(dot)48(dot)582`
2.  [0-23]  `112(dot)115(dot)48(dot)`
3.  [16-23] `48(dot)`
4.  [16-18] `48`
5.  [23-26] `582`
```

control one by one your cases in [here](https://regex101.com/r/sP1oN5/1)

Comment: interesting, im going to test this a bit more

Comment: It doesn't work for this:
112<test>115<test>48<test>582
but it works for this
112dot115dot48dot582

Comment: this also only works for dot, the ip separator could be any string, not just "dot".

Comment: All I know seperator should be certain value. It can be cause issues.

Comment: Added regex101 url, you can check your cases one by one.

Comment: It will say `12x23.34-45` as valid.

Comment: You are right @afzalex, but the seperators must be same. Otherwise all results can be valid.

Comment: But considering the heading of the OP these answers are not solving the problem. @İlkerKorkut

Answer (score 0):

You will need to capture group to accomplish this and use Non number `D`.

```
public boolean isIP(String test) {
    String regex = "\\d+(\\D+)\\d+\\1\\d+\\1\\d+";
    return test.matches(regex);
}
```

Here I have used regex : `\d+(\D+)\d+\1\d+\1\d+`
It is equivalent to : -

```
  \d+          (\D+)       \d+         \1          \d+          \1         \d+
numbers_1 non-numbers_1 numbers_2 non-numbers_1 numbers_3 non-numbers_1 numbers_4
```

Or you can further reduce the above regex to `\d+(\D+)\d+(\1\d+){2}`

Comment: 1231231128.123.23.121212312 ,  it will say this ip is valid.

Comment: The above answer is for : **How do i check to see if there are repeated patterns in a string**

Comment: you said valid, then what it means 0 to 255 ?

Comment: please read my above comment. I am saying this is to check repeated pattern.

Comment: And I posted this answer because as you can see nobody marked this, and in their answer they are saying `12x23.34-45` as valid. And I have not edited my answer. it will still say valid to `1231231128.123.23.121212312`. @İlkerKorkut

Comment: Yes, it means this is not valid. Anyway, this is boring subject, Welcome to Network101 :)

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class App
{
    private static String IPV4_REGEX ="^(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})\\.(\\d{1,3})$";
    private static final Pattern IP4_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(IPV4_REGEX);

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        String test1 = "198<string>12<string>88<string>201";
        String test2 = "198(foo)12(foo)88(foo)201";
        if(isIP(test1)) {
            System.out.println("Yep, it's an ip");
        }
        if(isIP(test2)) {
            System.out.println("Yep, it's an ip");
        }
    }

    public static boolean isIP(String input) {

        String[] chunks = input.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "x").split("x+");
        if (chunks.length != 4) {
            System.out.println("not valid ");
            return false; 
        }

        String ip = chunks[0] + "." + chunks[1] + "." + chunks[2] + "." + chunks[3];
        return IP4_PATTERN.matcher(ip).matches();
    }
}
```